# Jenkins promoting: empty classpath entries not allowed

Tags: jenkins, groovy, promoting

I have a freestyle jenkins job B which will run after the run of job A.
Now I choose:

- Promote builds when...
- Custom Groovy script

I check Groovy Sandbox and I define a simple groovy script.
When I try to save my job I got this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: JENKINS-37599: empty classpath entries not allowed
```

I have to define a `class path entry`: JAR file path or URL

Definition:

> A path or URL to a JAR file. This path should be approved by an
>   administrator or a user with the RUN_SCRIPT permission, or the script
>   fails. If the file or files are once approved, they are treated
>   approved even located in another path.

I really don't know to what file I have to point or what I have to do. Why isn't it just working when I check the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

This is a jenkins bug. It requires removing that Classpath entry every time before saving the job. I found a workaround, to set the value to any of the existing jars, like `https://your-jenkins-host/jnlpJars/slave.jar`. This won't affect script execution and won't require you to remember removing that stupid UI block every time you update your jenkins job config.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I clicked the red box with the white "X" to close that additional classpath window. I then saved the script.